# Can I make deb files for documents and other non-binary content?

Tags: packaging, deb

I would like to create .deb files with no binary content (*.odt files, for example).

The idea is to create a file that contains didactic files to learn certain discipline and an automatically package downloader, to get needed packages for discipline learning. For example, C# *.pdf tutorials followed for the download of MonoDevelop (C# IDE), for C# programming classes.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the package do not publish in public space, but that is only for your own local use, you can make the deb package by the below steps.

In this example, Package name: doc-sample, Package version: 0.1, the final installing directory is /usr/share/doc/doc-sample/sample-docs.

**Step1: Prepare directories to make the deb package.**

The name of directory need to include version number.

```
mkdir -p doc-sample-0.1/sample-docs
cd doc-sample-0.1
```

Then, add the documents which you want to install , in **doc-sample-0.1/sample-docs** directory.

**Step2: Prepare debian directory in default form.**

Run the below command in **doc-sample-0.1** directory.

```
dh_make -n -s -e (mail_address)
```

(mail_address): ex. **user@example.com**

If it is the form of a mail address, it does not matter even if it is not the mail address actually used anything.

**Step3: Remove unneccesary texts.**

```
rm debian/*.ex debian/*.EX debian/README.Debian debian/README.source
```

**Step4: Make the setting file named "(package_name).install" to install documents.**

```
nano debian/doc-sample.install
```

Describe using the form: (documents_directory_name) space (install_directory)

```
sample-docs  usr/share/doc/doc-sample
```

When you install the final deb package, the **sample-docs** folder will install to /usr/share/doc/doc-sample directory in this case. (Caution: each files are compressed in .gz form)

**Step5: Building deb package.**

If you will build the deb package only for your own local use, you can skip promptings for the GPG signatures on the .dsc file and the .changes file.

Run the below command in **doc-sample-0.1** directory.

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

So, you can get the deb package named **doc-sample_0.1_i386.deb** in upper directory.

If you want to publish in a public space (ex. PPA), you need to consider the license of a document, and sign the .dsc file and the .changes file by using GPG key.

For details, please refer to the documents for developers.

Comment: Is it possible to set what folder to "dh_make" and "dpkg-buildpackage" use, without "cd"?

Comment: The above description is premised on having changed the directory with `cd doc-sample-0.1` at the first step. They can not use, unless using `cd` to the top directory of the project containing a version number.

Comment: "(Caution: each files are compressed in .gz form)" How can you avoid the documents being compressed in `.gz` format?

Comment: Although it does not understand well, by this method(using `dpkg-buildpackage` command), I think that it will be installable only as the binary packages.